# How to set the url in IHTMLDocument2 without it navigating to a new page

Tags: url, c#-4.0, mshtml, ihtmldocument2

How do I set the url of an `htmldocument` after I've written to it. For example:

```
WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
wb.Navigate(new Uri(location, UriKind.Absolute));
IHTMLDocument2 myDoc = new HTMLDocumentClass();
myDoc.write(new object[] { wb.DocumentText});
myDoc.close();
```

If I do `myDoc.url = "http://www.google.com"` it attempts to load google.
How do I set the url without having it attempt to load that url?

Comment: Hmm. If it would not load google, than you would have an HTML document object in an inconsistent state. It may contain an empty DOM, or the DOM of some website, but its URL property would hold the URL of google...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These steps should give you a document with correct URL and your own content:

1. Create document directly from URL (so you don't have to set the URL later)
2. Stop document download (because you don't need the content)
3. Fill document with your content

This code shows how to do it:

```
// 1. Create new document from URL
IHTMLDocument2 NewDoc = (wb.Document as IHTMLDocument4).createDocumentFromUrl("http://www.stackoverflow.com", "null");
// 2. Immediately stop navigating; the URL is still set
NewDoc.execCommand("Stop", false, null);
// 3. Now write your stuff to the document
// ...
```

Note: It's hard to guess how much content can be downloaded between steps 1 and 2 because loading happens asynchronously. So it's probably good to check if the document is indeed empty before doing step 3. If not, clear the document and proceed.

Comment: Even though the commands are right after each other, it still makes an http request...even if it's aborted. If there really is no other way, I'll accept this in a few days.